# How do I install package Microsoft.NETCore.Jit 1.0.2 to a Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0 project?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, .net-standard

I am trying to upgrade all of my pre-existing PCL libraries into the .NETStandard portable libraries (using Visual Studio 2017) and have found the experience very distressing.

Having gone through the motions I now find that my Xamarin.iOS project cannot reference my .NETStandard1.3 project due to something to do with the Microsoft.NETCore.Jit which seems to relate to the need for the Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility library required by another one of my packages which is necessary for the NETStandard.Library.

Should I be able to reference this package in Xamarin.iOS? I'm running fully up to date software on a Mac and using the Xamarin Studio there.

Error in Xamarin is:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Jit 1.0.2'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: any success with this?

Comment: @MichałŻołnieruk not exactly, I found that one of my libraries was forcing me to import the Jit project. It turned out to be a SignalR library which Microsoft just happened to magically update to support my situation.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Does anybody found a solution? In my case, I'm trying to install Google.Sheets.API v4 to access Google Sheets

Comment: @Levimatt, I found that many of my troubles went away when I switched to using the new format for netstandard2.0 projects throughout. The old PCL libraries, even when updated still had legacy issues. It's a massive headache.

Comment: How did you do when you switched to use a new format for netstandard 2.0 projects?

Comment: @Levimatt, I created a new netstandard2.0 project type alongside (using a different project name) and then simply cut and pasted the classes into it from the older project. I had to re-add the NuGet references as applicable (a lot less references and I avoided copying the project.json and project.json.lock files)

Comment: JIT is not supported on platforms such as iOS, as the memory model is incompatible. Don't waste your time on that.